# Python - Pandas - Options

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance

I am attempting to create a scanner that connects to yahoo finance and scans for all options contracts with 20000 volume based on tickers located in a csv file. This is in python and i'm relying heavily on pandas. I would like it to return the ticker and even the options symbol would be nice. I keep getting the error: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute "upper".

Here is the code:

```
from pandas_datareader.data import Options
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import datetime

tickers = ['GOOG','MSFT']


for i in tickers:
    option = Options(i,'yahoo')

    if i.volume > 20000:
        print i

    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Please look up http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. People will be able to help better if you give them some minimal subset of your data with your code.

Comment: made the changes. Error is online 12 "str object has no attribute volume"

Comment: i is either "GOOG" or "MSFT". Why should it have an attribute volume? Maybe replace by option.volume > 20000.... But we don't know your Options objects

Comment: I'm new to programming so how can i better explain the problem at hand? thanks

Comment: Thanks. I figured that out. I posted another question here if you have the time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36188704/error-the-truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-python-pandas