# Python Pandas Truth Value of a Series in Ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have an empty array I've attempting to append based on values in Col1 and Col2. If a numerical value above zero is present in either column, append the array based on the corresponding value.

For example:

```
Col1 Col2
1         2
2         3
0         0
4         2
```

Output should be:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
1        2       [1,2,2]
2        3       [1,1,2,2,2]
0        0       []
4        2       [1,1,1,1,2,2]
```

Code so far returns 'the truth value of a series is ambiguous.' I'm familiar with this error in [context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36188704/error-the-truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-python-pandas) of other topics but can't seem to reconcile this against mine.

```
df = pd.read_csv('rawdata.csv')

x_array =[]

for x in df['emails_opened'], df['emails_clicked']:
    if (x > 0 & pd.notnull(x) & x != '' & x in df['emails_opened']):
        x_array == np.append(x_array, x * [2])
    elif (x > 0 & pd.notnull(x) & x != '' & x in df['emails_clicked']):
        x_array == np.append(x_array, x * [3])
    else: 0
print x_array
```

Any help is hugely appreciated!

Comment: I don't think this syntax `for x in df['emails_opened'], df['emails_clicked']:
` is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need:

```
#replace to 0 by conditions
m1 = (df['Col2'] > 0) & (df['Col2'].notnull()) & (df['Col2'].astype(str) != '') 
m2 = (df['Col1'] > 0) & (df['Col1'].notnull()) & (df['Col1'].astype(str) != '') 

col1 = df['Col1'].where(m1, 0)
col2 = df['Col2'].where(m2, 0)

#repeat array by filtered values, last create list and for no values add empty list
a = pd.Series(np.repeat([1] * len(col1), col1), 
              index = np.repeat(col1.index, col1))

a = a.groupby(level=0).apply(list).reindex(df.index, fill_value=[])

b = pd.Series(np.repeat([2] * len(col2), col2), 
              index = np.repeat(col2.index, col2))

b = b.groupby(level=0).apply(list).reindex(df.index, fill_value=[])


df['Col3'] = a + b
print (df)
   Col1  Col2                Col3
0     1     2           [1, 2, 2]
1     2     3     [1, 1, 2, 2, 2]
2     0     0                  []
3     4     2  [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

Comment: Thank you, Jezrael. I'm getting an error, "Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'" from the above. Looks like it relates to the fact that col2 has no values for some rows, which I thought the != '' would account for.

Comment: What is your pandas version? Last is `0.21.0`. Maybe it help. Also what row of code return error?

Comment: I'm on 0.21.0. Looks like the gap is when blanks are present in any list. I fixed a SQL script to replace blanks with 0s and it works great. Thank you for the help!